# Weird MySQL syntax error with simple CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

**Error:**

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'â€˜00000000000â€™ membership_status
>   ENUM(â€˜goldâ€™,â€˜silverâ€™,â€˜bronzeâ€™,' at line 5

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE members(
member_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(60)NOT NULL,
birthday DATE NOT NULL,
phone CHAR(10)NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘00000000000’,
membership_status ENUM(‘gold’,‘silver’,‘bronze’,‘nam’)NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘nam’,
PRIMARY KEY(member_id)    
)
```

Comment: Don't you have any character encoding issue ? 
How do you send your request ? with php ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess it was the funky single quotes you're trying to use. Try this with standard `'` single quotes

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    member_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(60)NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    phone CHAR(10)NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000000',
    membership_status ENUM('gold','silver','bronze','nam') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nam',
    PRIMARY KEY(member_id)
)
```

Comment: which buttons do i press on the keyboard for stanadard quote marks..?

Comment: for me on a UK keyboard it is the key in between the semi-colon `;` and hash `#`. It should be a straight up quote, no angle on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE members(
  member_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(60)NOT NULL,
  birthday DATE NOT NULL,
  phone CHAR(10)NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  membership_status ENUM('gold','silver','bronze','nam')NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nam',
  PRIMARY KEY(member_id)    
)
```

I changed the single quotes to plain ' and your default value for phone was also 1 to many 0s

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes used are not recognized by the database server. Replace those fancy quotes with the regular one **'** and you will be okay. 
Note that you'll encounter problems in other programs as long as you use that kind of quotes as they are not the proper quotes to be used.

Hope this helps.