# Escaping special characters in phpMyAdmin query

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I am trying to replace the string 1"/850 in the description field of a Magento database with 1-inch/850. I have come up with some variations of this

```
update catalog_product_entity_text set value = replace(value, ‘1"/850’, ‘1-inch/850’);
```

I have tried breaking with something like 1\"/850 or other variations and I keep getting an error message. Any suggestions as to the right syntax to use in this case?

Comment: `I keep getting an error message` what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using curly quotes. MySQL only understands the straight ones, so write '1"/850' and '1-inch/850'.

If this is not the issue, what error message do you get?

Comment: good catch, if that is truly the problem, then it is for the second time today... since yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728542/weird-mysql-syntax-error-with-simple-create-table-statement